Prevent users to use Copilot Edge
I want to prevent users from using Copilot Edge to create a summary of my displayed website.
Is there any way to do this? Robots.txt?
I don't want to switch of Copilot Edge completely - just on my website.

You can try to exclude the site from search results to see if it can prevent access to Copilot summarization. From this doc, summarization isn't supported on sites protected by Purview DLP Policies, MAM Policies and MDA Policies, but I think that needs configuration on an organization.

@YuZhou: I want to protect a publicly visible website from being accessed by Edge Copilot. The way via the policies you described won't work, will it?

No, I think it won't. The policies need to be set from the client side which you can't control. You can try the excluding the site from search results way.
